# Wordpress apply_filters() Arguments Missing

Tags: plugins, filters

I'm customizing a Woocommerce Wordpress site.

In the Woocommerce product class (`class-wc-product.php`) the `get_price` function applies a filter as follows:

```
function get_price() {
    return apply_filters('woocommerce_get_price', $this->price, $this);
}
```

In my functions.php I want to add a filter as follows:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_price');

function custom_price($price, $product) {
    ...
}
```

When I call this I get the following PHP warning:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for custom_price()
```

Why is the second argument missing? Is `$this` not sent to the filter call?

Comment: Maybe `apply_filters('woocommerce_get_price', … );` is called somewhere else without the second argument? Did you search for such a case?

Comment: It's called only once as far as I can see

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's missing the second argument because you didn't tell WordPress you wanted it with your `add_filter` call.  By default, actions and filters only get one argument.  Try this:

```
<?php
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_price', 10, 2);

function custom_price($price, $product) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer Chris, exactly why I love this site. I learn something new every day.

Comment: For the longest time I didn't even know the value for parameter 4 dictates the number of arguments to pass in. TY

Answer (score 1):

The warning is a result of the second argument in your function custom_price(). The filter provides only one variable on the call and I can't remember if this is the product/post ID or the price. The code docs indicate that it returns a string so I'd presume it's the price.

You can hopefully find the documentation at http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/apidocs/index.html

If you need the product at this point you'll have to use:

```
function custom_price( $price ) {

    global $product;

}
```

If all else fails simply echo $price to see if you can tell if it's a product ID or a price. Then adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your insights @chrisguitarguy's anwser seems to have done the trick for me.

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly a more elegant solution.